# Why is my App sending its data to another Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I made a new mockup app(*ManualRecyclerView*) to test out how to fetch data **Firebase Realtime Database in RecyclerView - GridView**.

So I inject the dependencies and connect the app to Firebase.

I set up the basic UI and the code for the adapter.

BUT! As soon as I test it out and input the data, the **data goes to another Firebase Database**(*Sweet Dreams*). Which is the database for the other project im working on.

What bothers me is that, I have already corrected the `.json` file

**.json file**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "493876747245",
    "firebase_url": "https://manualrecyclerview.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "manualrecyclerview",
    "storage_bucket": "manualrecyclerview.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:493876747245:android:aece709f70cbe8d86ce5e4",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "dcbrh.ph.manualrecyclerview"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "493876747245-t3ekrflfg6k4a7qirbt7fqe065grm6pr.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDJItnNjZ72-ZDVUXzpR_nK7ea6d31vcUY"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "493876747245-t3ekrflfg6k4a7qirbt7fqe065grm6pr.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
package dcbrh.ph.manualrecyclerview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter()

        button_storeMovie_main.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Storing data in FirebaseDatabase")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Storing data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            storeMovieInFirebaseDatabase()
        }
    }

    private fun storeMovieInFirebaseDatabase() {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
        val title = editText_inputTitle_main.text.toString()
        val price = editText_inputPrice_main.text.toString()
        val movieData = Movie(title, price)
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies/$uid/").setValue(movieData)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Data stored successfully | UID = $uid")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }
            .addOnFailureListener{
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Data failed to store")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data failed to store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }

    }
}

class Movie(val name: String, val price: String) {
    constructor(): this("", "")
}
```

**Main Adapter**

```
package dcbrh.ph.manualrecyclerview

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.card_view_layout.view.*

class MainAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    val productTitles = listOf("The Bird Box", "Extraction", "Bad Boys", "300 Spartans", "Project X")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productTitles.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellGrid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellGrid)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val productTitles = productTitles.get(position)
        holder.sight.apply {
            cardView_textView_title.text = productTitles
            cardView_textView_price.text = "Php20.00"
        }

    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val sight: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(sight) {

}
```

**Mockup app**
[ManualRecyclerView App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7jW6.png)

**Sweet Dreams database**
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtx8o.png)

None is being sent to ManualRecyclerView Database.

Comment: Your issue is certainly related to configuration.

Comment: Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Check if the .json file is the right one.

Comment: I have already checked the .json file and even downloaded it again but to no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, it looks like you are using the same Firebase project in both of your Android Studio projects. So carefully check your Firebase projects structure

Comment: where can i see this structure? Im still kinda new to firebase

Comment: you can open firebase console and see your existing projects